# Customizing the style and location of $session->flash's output in CakePHP 1.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm writing a simple web application using CakePHP version 1.2 (the latest) and am having an issue with displaying the flash message from the Session helper.  In my layout, there exists the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->renderElement('flash'); ?>
```

Which renders the following element:

```
<?php if($session->check('Message.flash')): ?>
     <?php $class = isset($error) ? 'contentError' : 'contentSuccess'; ?>
     <div class="contentBlockWrapper <?php echo $class; ?>">
         <div class="contentBlock">
             <div id="flashMessage" class="flash">
                 <?php $session->flash(); ?>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The desired behavior is that, if there's a flash message to be displayed, that it be displayed at the above location within the DOM so that it will be styled and positioned as I wish.

The problem is that, if there is a flash message, CakePHP is rendering it immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.  Now, it also renders the containers described above in the correct location, but simply doesn't write the text where I want it.

I've tried flushing the output buffer into a variable within my view and echo'ing that, but to no avail.  I've also read that some folks have tried using named keys to indicate the specific message they want displayed, but that isn't appropriate here because the text that I want to display is being displayed, just in the wrong location.

Any assistance would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that no matter where you place the call to render the element, cake will always put it right after the body tag? In my app (just tested this), it renders it wherever I have the $session->flash call (looking at the generated source, within the DOM).

Are you sure you've got it right in the layout?  Will you post your layout view (use bin.cakephp.org and leave a link).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe it's because I have the whole mess in an element instead of within the view itself.  I'll try moving it out of the element and see if that works - thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably have a leftover in your layout which says

```
$session->flash();
```

So the flash is rendered there and cleared. This is why it is not rendered in your element.

Check your `~/app/views/layouts/default.ctp` (or other if you're not using the default) and let us know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that if you used translation function when calling setFlash() in your controller, you passed "true" as the second parameter to it. Like so:

$this->Session->setFlash(__('My Message Here', TRUE));

Otherwise, the message will be echoed, not returned! You will just see it prepended to your page's HTML code and the message sent to setFlash will be undefined and thus will not show up in the place where you expect it to.